# ModX большие траблы с CMS и с Сервером nginx + apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, modx, логирование

С утра ищу решение своей проблемы и от отчаяния решил обратиться к СтакОверфлоувцам.
Возникла следующая проблема: ничего не предвещало беды, как вдруг сайт на ModX начал грузить только главную страницу.
А, например, страницы `/404` или `/kviz`, или `/sitemap.xml` or `/robots.txt` вообще не грузят и постоянно разные ошибки (либо Too many redirects, либо 502 bad gtway nginx).
Причем, если отключить файлы .htaccess, то тогда на все перечисленные выше адреса вылетает 404 not found (и не тот который я на CMS 404 создавал, а просто надпись)

Мое предположение было, что сайт создает овер много запросов, апач не успевает обработать и отправить НГИНКСУ и nginx выдает ошибку.

В Файле .htaccess ничего еще не прописано было (стандартный ModX-овский)

В логах ModX обнаружил, что у меня криво работает phpthumbOf (а точнее он дублирует пути и вместо `assets/gallery/2/2.jpg` выдает `assets/gallery/assets/gallery/2/2.jpg` и потому в логах вылетает ошибка о невозможности создать превью)

Мое последнее преположение, что именно из-за phpthumbOf и зависает апач и НгинкС

Помогите пожалуйста разобравться с этой проблемой

Логи ModX: https://pastebin.com/CGyH5Qw1

Comment: Без nginx попробуйте. Зачем вам дополнительный слой в системе, если вы ищете ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Фууууф. Проблема заключалась в том, что при настройке "Группы ресурсов" на ModX (т.е. чтобы, например, менеджеры не видели некоторые страницы сайта такие как: /404, /sitemap.xml, /robots.txt и др) страницы, необходимые скрыть от манагеров, попадали в группу ресурсов админа. И по какой-то необъяснимой причине они начинали блокироваться для просмотра в браузере. Ну и 2ая проблема тоже каким-то образом после удаления групп ресурсов (я про логи), сама себя вылечила.
Всем спасибо )